# Questions about GM_getValue, and finding a userscript data storage solution other than GM_setValue

Tags: userscripts

I debugged and found that Tampermonkey loads all the script data (stored via GM_setValue) on loading.

[image: all data]

Is that really the case, or am I misunderstanding GM_getValue?

The problem is that I have some relatively large data in my script, and they don't need to be loaded most of the time. I feel the need to store these data in a different way, but the question is how should I do it?

I've considered the common web storage solutions, but all have cross-domain issues. The option of using `postMessage` with `<iframe>` in conjunction to cross domains doesn't seem to work for userscripts either.

Answer (score 1):

Old Greasemonkey (GM3) before Firefox 57 (2017-11-14) had the **synchronous** `GM_getValue` & `GM_setValue`.

Since Firefox 57, all storage APIs are **asynchronous** and Greasemonkey adopted the asynchronous `GM.getValue` & `GM.setValue` which gets/sets the data at the time the API is called.

FireMonkey on Firefox offers asynchronous `GM.getValue` & `GM.setValue` and semi-synchronous `GM_getValue` & `GM_setValue`.

Tampermonkey & Violentmonkey offer quasi-synchronous storage method of `GM_getValue` & `GM_setValue`. Their `GM.getValue` & `GM.setValue` are aliases of the quasi-synchronous. That is why they need to load the entire storage data in every page.